# how to make Intent.ACTION_CALL in Array adapter android facing activity not found exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

> i am using array adapter to load the data in listview. in list view i have phone number , if the user clicks the number , calling function should hapen.
>
> My array adapter class as follows

```
public class PendingDeliveryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PendingDeliveryPojoClass>{

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
public PendingDeliveryAdapter(Context context,List<PendingDeliveryPojoClass> data)
{
    super(context,R.layout.listview_pending_delivery,data);
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

> And get view method so on...
>
> code to call the calling functions in button click

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
              phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse(holder.delivery_phone_number.getText().toString()));
              try {
                 context.startActivity(phoneIntent);
              } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                 Toast.makeText(getContext(), 
                 "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
        }
```

> i am facing activity not found exception . how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct use of [***`Intent.ACTION_CALL`***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL) is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
startActivity(intent);
```

---

So `tel:` is missing from data of intent, which you are setting. To make working your code,
Change

```
phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse(holder.delivery_phone_number.getText().toString()));
```

with

```
phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + holder.delivery_phone_number.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing i thought "tel:" is not required . but it helps me

Comment: @John your most welcome :). Congs you got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call intent this way

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

     Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
     callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + temp1));
     context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

but have you tried this after initializing your Intent to Intent.CALL_ACTION?

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 callIntent .setPackage("com.android.phone");
 callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + temp1));
 context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

specify the package name?

hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

In your Adapter put this code:

```
String phoneNumber = editPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
Strin uri = phoneNumber.trim();
Uri call = Uri.parse("tel:" + uri);

intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(call);
itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```